# 301 redirects: match querystring, don't append it to new redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've set up a number of 301 redirects in an .htaccess file, but I'm having problems with a query string that makes the redirect not match.

Example:

```
Redirect 301 /about/history/?lang=fr http://www.newdomain.com/fr/history
Redirect 301 /about/history/ http://www.newdomain.com/nl/history
```

So `olddomain.com/about/history/?lang=fr` now matches the second rule and redirects to `http://www.newdomain.com/nl/history?lang=fr`.

I want it to take the `?lang=fr` literally and not append the querystring to the new redirect.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Redirect`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) takes an URL-*path*, which doesn't include the query string. So, the first `Redirect` never matches.

To achieve what you want, you can try some sort of [content negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html) or use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=fr
RewriteRule /about/history/ http://www.newdomain.com/fr/history? [R,L]
RewriteRule /about/history/ http://www.newdomain.com/nl/history [R,L]
```

When everything works as you expect, you can change `R` to `R=301`.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using PHP redirects instead, worked better for this scenario.