# Redirect old .asp links to new url

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The site was initially hosted on a Windows Server and it was created using .asp programming language. Now it has been moved to a linux server running cPanel/WHM and the new site is built using Wordpress and WooCoomerce (the site is an online shop).

I need to do some .htacess redirects from old .asp urls to the new links

Example:

```
old URL: http://website.com.au/products.asp?cat=110
new URL: http://www.website.com.au/product-category/pearls/
```

What I did try is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

Redirect 301 /products.asp?cat=110 http://www.website.com.au/product-category/pearls/
```

For some reason the redirect is not working and I get a 404 page not found error.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Querystring might be an issue... See this: [301 redirects: match querystring, don't append it to new redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16162586/301-redirects-match-querystring-dont-append-it-to-new-redirect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not match against query strings in a Redirect Directive, you need to match against query strings using a rewriteCond, try:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat=110$
RewriteRule ^products\.asp$ http://website.com.au/product-category/pearls/? [L,NC,R]
```

An empty question mark at the end of the target url is important if you don't want the old query strings to be appended to the target url.

Comment: It works!!! Thank you so much! One more thing.
I will do exactly the same for other rules like?

Meaning that /products.asp?cat=102 should go to 
http://website.com.au/product-category/diamonds/ let's say...  and so on...

Comment: Yes you can add multiple Rewriteconds and rules same as above for other query  strings ,just change the **R** to **R=301** if you want to make the redirect permanet.

Comment: Ok, thank you.

One more final question and I'm done. After I'm done with all those redirects, what rule should I add in order to redirect any other .asp links to main page?

So let's say I am adding 10 rules like the ones from the example. Then any other requests to an .asp link except those initial 10 will be redirected to the main page.

Thanks,

Comment: To redirect `*.asp` to `/mainpage/` add the following rule bellow those 10 redirects

`RewriteRule \.asp$ /mainpage/ [L,R]`

Make sure this rule is bellow your other rules and the **/mainpage/** is not a .asp page otherwise it will conflict with them.